# Basic auth for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, basic-authentication

I need to pass to iframe url, that require basic auth.
Method http://username:password@example.com is deprecated and workd on Google Chrome, but not on IE.

I tried method with reversed proxy, but in this case i need to use original url (relative paths). Url is to external website which has not configured CORS.

Is any solution for this problem?
Ultimately i can write to programists from destination website to configure CORS, if only solution is use javascript and AJAX request.

Comment: If you’re going to expose the credentials in client-side code, then you might as well remove the HTTP Auth altogether …

Comment: CORS is the way to go. Here is a good instruction on how to enable CORS: http://enable-cors.org/index.html